# Configure CORS response headers on AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create a new service using AWS API Gateway, but I found out the browser automatically calls OPTIONS method in order to obtain CORS information.

The problem is that AWS API Gateway does not offer a native way to configure CORS headers.

Is it possible to create a Lambda Script in order to respond to OPTIONS method?

Comment: Did you take a look at [Enable CORS for a Method in API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)?  Did that not work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using `{proxy+}` endpoint, you must handle CORS HTTP requests in the Lambda function. The implementation depends on the framework you're using. For Express, the easiest solution is to simply use [Express CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

If you don't want to handle `CORS` requests by `Lambda`, try changing the settings of your `Lambda Method` to handle `CORS` on the `API Gateway` level.

Here's a detailed official tutorial for [CORS setup on AWS API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html).

It's also critical that you allow header `X-Api-Key` in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` otherwise auth won't work and you'll get errors.

**EDIT:** In November 2015 the API Gateway team added a new feature to simplify CORS setup.

Comment: enabling CORS setup in api gateway in the not enough if your api gateway is configured as lambdaproxy

Comment: @Chandru I agree, the aws docs says that for proxy setups, the response has to come from the http backend, what should this look for like for node/express?

Comment: Try creating one `{proxy+}` endpoint and have all the requests forwarded to the Lambda function.

Comment: This answer is not correct as stated above. The one below should be marked.

Comment: This answer is correct. However Lambda-level configuration is needed for {proxy+} endpoints because all requests are just passed through from API Gateway.

Comment: @Alisson You should see `{proxy+}` in your API Gateway resource.

Answer (score 56):

If you have lambda-proxy enabled, you need to set the CORS headers manually:

```js
module.exports.hello = function(event, context, callback) {

    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Required for CORS support to work
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ "message": "Hello World!" })
    };

    callback(null, response);
};
```

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#enabling-cors

Answer (score 6):

Here is a sample, I hope this helps you:

```
...
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Allow from anywhere 
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET" // Allow only GET request 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(response)
    }
}
```

For more information please check this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Answer (score 3):

If you're using JQuery $.ajax, it will send the X-Requested-With with the POST following the OPTIONS request, so you need to make sure when setting up your OPTIONS access-control-accept-headers on AWS API to include that header: X-Requested-With along with the others.

Comment: where did you discover this? is it documented? how were you able to add the header in the API Gateway resources "Enable CORS" form?

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for HTTP API Gateway with ANY method.
If you use authorizer on ANY method, your authorizer will reject the OPTIONS request as it doesn't contain an Authorization/Bearer token.
Solution is simple:
Next to the ANY route, create OPTIONS route with the very same path and no authorizer, pointing to lambda function. Then in lambda, add

```
const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0, no-store, must-revalidate",
    Pragma: "no-cache",
    Expires: 0
};
data = {
        multiValueHeaders: {},
        isBase64Encoded: false,
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: headers,
        body: ""
    }
if (event.httpMethod == "OPTIONS") {
    return context.done(undefined, data)
}
```

This worked for me.